# Error when calling nextElement of an Enumeration

Tags: java, jar, enumeration

I'm trying to add files to a .jar file.
My problem is that JarOutputStream the old .jar file overwrites.

So I created this code:

```
Enumeration<JarEntry> enu = game.entries()
while(enu.hasMoreElements()){
    File f = doThing(game.getInputStream(enu.nextElement()));
    add(f,os);
}
```

game is a `JarFile`.
`add(File, JarOutputStream)` adds a file to the `JarOutputStream` and `os` is a `JarOutputStream`.

But if I try this code i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.zip.ZipError: jzentry == 0,
 jzfile = 576741376,
 total = 57,
 name = C:\Users\Jorolf\Desktop\XXX.jar,
 i = 1,
 message = null
```

(I get the error when calling enu.nextElement())

Edit:
I was reading and writing the same file at the same time so I changed it so I write to a temporary file and afterwards replace the old file with the temporary.

Comment: `My problem is that JarOutputStream the old .jar file overwrites. ` Do you mean you are trying to write the file that you are reading at the same time?

Comment: @copeg not at the same time. It should read all Files from the jar file and then write everything to the new one.( At the end I'm doing os.close())

Comment: `At the end I'm doing os.close()` Still unclear, and still sounds like you are writing at the same time (just because `os.close` is not called doesn't mean it won't be writing). I recommend posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to clear up any assumptions that may or may not be made